# What's the difference between 'Enum : Type' and simply 'Enum'

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I am trying to understand a few things about `Enums` in general and how they can work with `Chars` specifically.  Below is my example I am working from:

```
public enum AuditInteractionTypes
{
    Authorized = 'A',
    Created = 'C',
    Revised = 'R',
    Extracted = 'E',
    Deleted = 'D'
}
```

First, what's the difference between declaring them `enum AuditInteractionTypes` or `enum AuditInteractionTypes : char`

Second, I have seen the numerous post's about trying to use `Enums` with `chars` and how to "make" it work back and forth.  Possible stupid question but why couldn't I simply go back and forth as a `string`.

So, for example, `Authorized = "A"`.

I have am using Linq To SQL as my DAL if that matters though I am asking, I hope, a broader level question not specific to my environment.

Comment: Mind you that declaring enumerations with a base type of char is illegal in the C# language.

Comment: *Deriving* from `char` is not valid, but using `char` literals to represent the per-item value is:     `enum Fruit : int
    {
        Apple = 'A',
        Orange = 'O',
        Banana = 'B'
    }`

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: so why the ` :int` part?  Not understanding that.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin That is just the underlying data type the enumeration is stored in. A `char` can be used where the enumeration data type has implicit conversion to `char`.

Comment: Minor nitpick: the naming guidelines state that your enumeration should be named `AuditInteractionType`; you use the plural form only when the `FlagAttribute` is applied to the enumeration.

Comment: @casperOne Thanks, missed that one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It dictates the underlying type that will be used for storage of the enumeration.

When you use `enum` without anything else, it uses an `int` as the underlying storage type.

When you use `enum : <type>`, it uses that type as the underlying storage type.

In your case, you're trying to make the underlying type of type `char`, but that's not valid, according to [the C# reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx):

> The approved types for an enum are byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

If you want to store `char` values, then you have two options.

You could use an underlying type of [`ushort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cbf1574z.aspx) (it's an unsigned 16-bit integer like `char`), like so:

```
public enum AuditInteractionTypes : ushort
{
    Authorized = 'A',
    Created = 'C',
    Revised = 'R',
    Extracted = 'E',
    Deleted = 'D'
}
```

`char` has an implicit conversion to `ushort` so the above works.  Also, you can easily compare the two.

If [you want to use a string as the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13841923/whats-the-difference-between-enum-type-and-simply-enum/13841959#comment19052623_13841959) then I'd recommend an `enum`-like class, like so:

```
public static class AuditInteractionTypes
{
    // You can make these static readonly if they are likely to change.
    public const string Authorized = "A";
    public const string Created = "C";
    public const string Revised = "R";
    public const string Extracted = "E";
    public const string Deleted = "D";
}
```

This class will then pretty much look the same as an `enum` and code the same way.

Note, the same trick can be done with any type, but generally those types should be *completely* immutable.  `string` fills this guideline nicely, being completely immutable (as are most system value types, and other value types, if you've designed them correctly).

Comment: Really, so why all the post's (like here-->http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78600/C-Enum-with-Char-Valued-Items) that illustrate conversion methods back and forth for Enums Char's?  What am I missing?

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Char's are technically not a valid "base type" for an enumeration when declared in C#, so what you are seeing in that article is a work around.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin - If you want to get a string from the _value_ of the `char` enumeration, you need to convert the numeric value (which is what a `char` is) to a string representation.

Comment: I see, might be pure ignorance talking here but is it simpler working with Enums whose value is a `String` or a `Char`?

Comment: From the link you posted: The key discovery was the conversion from the enum to char, you need to cast it to char first, and only then you can have your char value, because since the .NET Framework thinks it's an int, you must convert it to char (so it translates the int to the equivalent char on the ASCII table, like the old method chr()).

Comment: @RefractedPaladin You use the enumerated type in code as a string, as in your case `AuditInteractionTypes.Created`, but the underlying data doesn't *need* to be a string or char, and I don't see how it makes sense otherwise. The only time I ever want an enum as a string is usually for outputting to certain places (like document databases, configuration files, or SpecFlow tests).

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Depends on your needs.  If it is better represented as a character, use that.  If you have to perform a lot of operations that are native to `string` on it, then go with that.  "Simpler" depends on your use.  However, it's always easy to call `ToString` on the `char` if you need to work with strings in a pinch.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Updated (and managed to salvage the bit at the end).

Comment: So, using the `:ushort` base type will allow me to use char values for my enums without an additional Convert Method or Parsing when I go to map this back to the database through the DAL...or would I still need to cast them `(char) Authorized` when I go to get the char value?

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Depends on the DAL; if it's a good one, then it should map automatically to a `ushort` in the database (or something that can hold it) as it will see the `enum` as a numeric type.  However, that might not be what you want in your database (you have to make the determination which is better for you).  If the normalization works for you (it's part of a defined set), then go with that, otherwise, you might have to make it free form (but it looks like the former).

Comment: @casperOne so if my Database requires a `char` my DAL would need to cast it correctly.

Comment: @RefractedPaladin Yes, if your database type is analogous to a .NET `char`, then you will have to make sure that your DAL handles this translation.  Depending on how it does type mapping, it might handle this automatically (depending on what implicit or explicit conversions the database allows).

Answer (score 2):

The "base type" of an enum must be an integral value type.  A string doesn't qualify, that's a reference type.

Not using the default (int) is typically only necessary when you interop with unmanaged code.  The C and C++ languages also allow specifying the size of an enum using the same base types.  With a corner case of long being useful when you have a lot of [Flags] enumeration values, allowing you to distinguish up to 64 flag values.

You could pick byte or short if you are really trying to squeeze storage requirements.  Which can speed up code due to better use of the cpu caches.  That in general doesn't turn out too well due to alignment requirements for other fields in a class or struct.  And you can lose the cache advantage when you manipulate such enum values, like testing their value or isolating a flag, 32-bit processors really like an int and you'll pay for the conversion.  Profiling is required.

Comment: The size used in operations (typ 32-bits) doesn't have to match the storage size.  Which is why you pay for it.  The essence of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to this one:

> Possible stupid question but why couldn't I simply go back and forth as a string.

You can use implementation like this:

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public enum AuditInteractionTypes
{
    [Description("A")] Authorized,
    [Description("C")] Created,
    [Description("R")] Revised,
    [Description("E")] Extracted,
    [Description("D")] Deleted
}
```

So basically every element will receive some string value.

Or You can use struct:

```
struct AuditInteractionTypes
{
    static string Authorized = "A";
    static string Created = "C";
    static int Revised = 0;
    static char[] Extracted = "E".ToCharArray(); //Not sure if this one is usefull
}
```